# How to optimize a query with hard left join?

Tags: postgresql

I have got a query

```
SELECT
"athlete"."id" AS "athlete_id"
FROM "athlete"
LEFT JOIN "athlete_in_game" ON athlete.id = athlete_in_game.id_athlete
LEFT JOIN "athlete_in_team" ON athlete.id = athlete_in_team.id_athlete
LEFT JOIN "game" ON 
    athlete_in_team.id_team = game.id_team_home OR 
    athlete_in_team.id_team = game.id_team_away OR
    athlete_in_game.id_game = game.id
LEFT JOIN "sport_competition" ON sport_competition.id_game = game.id
GROUP BY "athlete"."id"
```

I need to choose all athletes which played in competitions. But it could be that no data in table "athlete_in_game" for several games and in this case I take all athletes from table "athlete_in_team" for these games. Because of it I use double "OR" in the third left join. I need all written conditions but because of double "OR" it could work too long. Is the chance to optimize it anyway?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 0):

i think first you have to improve schema in first place . team related info should be separate table. and game should be separate . you don't have to do left join with `game` table i think . only left join on `athlete_in_game` and `athlete_in_team` would be enough. like So

```
SELECT
"athlete"."id" AS "athlete_id"
FROM "athlete"
LEFT JOIN "athlete_in_game" ON athlete.id = athlete_in_game.id_athlete
LEFT JOIN "athlete_in_team" ON athlete.id = athlete_in_team.id_athlete
JOIN "game" ON 
    athlete_in_team.id_team = game.id_team_home OR 
    athlete_in_team.id_team = game.id_team_away OR
    athlete_in_game.id_game = game.id
LEFT JOIN "sport_competition" ON sport_competition.id_game = game.id
GROUP BY "athlete"."id"
```